# How to set selected item(s) in a listView from a collection of an object

Tags: wpf, listview, datatemplate, itemtemplate

I'm setting up a WPF control using a ListView which displays a list of items from an observable collection of class objects (here - `AllSettingsCollection<MySettings>`) present in my Model. Where MySettings is a class which contains some hardware settings.

I am able to set the ItemSource of the list view as

```
ItemsSource="{Binding  Model.AllSettingsCollection}"
```

and display the name in each row using a DataTemplate (code below)
but i am not able to set the selected property of each row based on the IsSelected property.

Suppose the class (MySettings) is as below

```
public class MySettings
{
  public string Name{get; private set;}
  public string IsSelected{get; private set;}
}
```

and objects of this class are in the collection `AllSettingsCollection` which is an `ObservableCollection<MySettings>`

Now if i setup my ListView as below

```
<ListView
      Grid.Row="0"
      HorizontalContentAlignment="Stretch"
      ItemsSource="{Binding Model.AllSettingsCollection}"
      SelectionMode="Multiple"
      Style="{StaticResource ListViewStyle}">
      <ListView.View>
        <GridView AllowsColumnReorder="False">
          <GridViewColumn
            DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Name}"
            Header="Settings:" >
            <GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
              <DataTemplate>
                <TextBlock HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Text="{Binding}" />
              </DataTemplate>
            </GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
          </GridViewColumn>
          <GridView.ColumnHeaderContainerStyle>
            <Style BasedOn="{StaticResource NonResizableGridViewColumnHeaderStyle}" TargetType="{x:Type GridViewColumnHeader}">
            </Style>
          </GridView.ColumnHeaderContainerStyle>
        </GridView>
      </ListView.View>
      <ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
        <Style BasedOn="{StaticResource ListViewItemStyle}" TargetType="{x:Type ListViewItem}">
        </Style>
      </ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
    </ListView>
```

since my ListView.ItemsSource is the Model.AllSettingsCollection, i am able to generate each row with a name. but i am not able to find where i can set the property IsSelected of each row.

Where can i set the isSelected property of each row if the ListView, so ideally i could have have a statement like

```
<Setter Property="IsSelected" Value="{Binding IsSelected}"/>
```

which takes each row and marks it as selected or not based on the IsSelected property of the object in the collection.

Note: I would also like to have each rows isSelected have a changed event, which responds to if the user changes which set of items are selected, but this is something i will look at later.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Move the Setter into the ItemContainerStyle:

```
<ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
    <Style TargetType="ListViewItem">
        <Setter Property="IsSelected" Value="{Binding IsSelected}"/>
    </Style>
</ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
```

And make sure the source property is of type `bool` and has a public setter that fires a change notification:

```
public class MySettings : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    public string Name { get; private set; }

    private bool isSelected;
    public bool IsSelected
    {
       get { return isSelected; }
       set
       {
           isSelected = value;
           PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this,
               new PropertyChangedEventArgs(nameof(IsSelected)));
       }
    }
}
```

Comment: thanks! VS wasnt able to resolve the property but on running, it works :)